# String was not recognized as a valid Date Time error on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Greeting people...i develop a web..everything working fine till deployment...my question        is - why is it this error appear? because if i run the web on Visual Studio Server 
    everything fine...but when i deploy and run it on IIS server suddenly this error 
    appear..why is people? really need some help here..

```
string tarikh = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTarikh.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

the line is where the cause of error..thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

For this problem you have to go to the IIS

Go to IIS -> Select your Configured Website -> Click on **.NET Globalization**

From .NET Globalization, select **Culture** and **UI- Culture** as **English (United State) (en – US)**

Restart IIS by running command as iisreset through windows command prompt

Check application is giving same problem or not

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the server-side default culture is different to the one you've been using in development.

What format are you expecting the date to be in, anyway? You should either use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) or *at least* use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) specifying the appropriate `CultureInfo`. (For example, the culture of the user.)

Likewise I would suggest that you supply an appropriate `CultureInfo` to `ToString` - possibly `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: it still problem when i used this...string tarikh = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTarikh.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).toString();

Comment: @ApizZest: Well what was the text you were tryin to parse? Note that that wouldn't have been your *exact* code, given that `toString` should be `ToString`...

Comment: i try to parse eg : 04/22/2012 in datetime format into 2012-04-22 in string..yep..in my code it is ToString()..

Comment: @ApizZest: You need to give `DateTime.ParseExact` the *input* format, not the *output* format. I think you'll find your code easier to understand if you separate out parsing from formatting - store the parse result in a separate `DateTime` variable, *then* call `ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

You have different "regional setting" on your development machine and the web server.

Instead of calling Convert.ToDateTime(string), you could try to use the overloaded version Convert.ToDateTime(string, IFormatProvider) and specify in what format you expect the date to be in.

Some of us thinks that today's date is "2012-04-22" while other claims it is "4/22/2012" etc...

EDIT: Just do something like:

```
var  ci = new CultureInfo("xx-XX");
var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTarikh.Text, ci);
```

Where xx-XX is the code of the culture you want to work with. Look it up here:
http://sharpertutorials.com/list-of-culture-codes/

Answer (score 1):

Because the date you get from txtTarikh.Text is not parsed as date.
Probably on your local machine, your regional settings are different from your server.
Add a log and print txtTarikh.Text to see what returns at your server and also on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Issue is resolved by setting up .net globlization  settings in IIS

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8"  responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
```

change these lines in web.config and publish it again.. It worked for me.